# If statement within an If statement jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

Hey everyone I am having a little problem with my jQuery I am trying to validate several forms and check to see if the element exists and then check to see if the radio button is selected. but It keeps ignoring my code and submitting the form.

```
   else if ($('fieldset').is('.customer')) {
        if (!$('input:radio[name=i_am]').is(':checked')) {
            alert("Please tell us if your a new/exisiting customer");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have several forms using the same ID's and classes but this is the problem i am having? anyone know where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `ID`s **must** be unique in the DOM.

Comment: Ids must be unique and also to validate u must use some validation framework like Jquery validate

Comment: I forgot to add, when ever I am on a different form and there is no fieldset with the class ".customer" the alert prevents me from submitting the form.

Comment: @ParvSharma You don't need a validation framework to do validation. It may make you job more easy but it is not mandatory at all.

Comment: Sorry the id's are unique, there the same for different forms, all forms are on separate pages, it doesnt effect the form in any way. its just the trying to get my form to check if theres a class and then execute to check if my radio button under the name "i_am" is checked.

Comment: shouldn't it be `[name="i_am"]`?

Comment: @jakee That's what the jQuery used to say, but not anymore. 1 sec lemme get the ticket.

Comment: @jakee My mistake. For attributes it is still needed: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you change your code this way:

```
else if ($('fieldset').is('.customer') && !$('input:radio[name=i_am]').is(':checked')) {
    alert("Please tell us if your a new/exisiting customer");
    return false;
}
```